# Jpa Specification Criteria Api for searching range of dates

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria, specifications

If I want to check to apply Predicate for one particular date, I am able to do so as follows:

```
predicate = builder.between(root.<LocalDate>get('date'),startDate,endDate);
```

But now I want to apply for a range of dates.
i.e. if I have an appointment from -> 2020-07-20 to -> 2020-07-25 and,
therefore my range of date is (from, to) here I want to put a check in the predicate that, It want to extract appointment for the date 2020-07-23 then It should be between start and end date.
I don't know if this is a possible case. But as mentioned in above example
I want a query like:

```
predicate = builder.between(root.<LocalDate>get('range(from, to)'),startDate,endDate);
```

Comment: For `range of dates` show example

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to break it in to separate predicates based on `startDate`, `endDate`, `from` and `to`.

I'm not completely sure I got your intention right, but I think you want to check if the interval [from,to] is completely inside the interval `[startDate, endDate]`

You can do that with code similar to the following:

```
Predicate startsAfterBegin =  builder.greaterThan(root.get('from'), startDate);
Predicate endsBeforeEnd =  builder.lessThan(root.get('to'), endDate);
Predicate isContained = builder.and(startsAfterBegin, endsBeforeEnd);
```

Comment: Should not endsBeforeEnd be like, builder.lessThan(root.get('to'), endDate);
And yeah you got me I have to do exactly the same.